# Zimbra rebuild redolog folder

Tags: logging, zimbra

I have a mailserver with zimbra 8.6.0_ga 1153 version. I have a problem with redolog folder. The partition with redolog data is corrupted and is not recoverable. It is possible regenerate redolog files inside archive folder (/opt/zimbra/redolog/archive/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to restore the transactions if those transactions are lost. Redo logfiles are normaly moved to incremental backups, so maybe you can restore them from there.

Otherwise, start a full backup and that will give you a 'clean' start for the new redo logfiles.